# Rename a File if exists

Tags: java, eclipse, dialog

When I try to save a file with the file name that already exists, I need to prompt the user to rename the file in order to save. What is the better way to prompt the user rename the File f the same File exists in the directory?I need to implement this via the same dialog box I use to save the file.

```
File exportFile = new File(FilePath + "\\"+ FileName);
boolean exists = exportFile.exists();  

if (!exists) {  

    System.out.println("File does not exists");  
    // TODO code here             
}
else{  

    System.out.println( "File exists.");
    // TODO code here                                       
}
```

The code is to be implemented in the //TODO part. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`while(exists) { \\Prompt the user to enter another name & change "exists" status correspondingly}`

```
            while(exists) 
        {
         String temp=dis.readLine();
         exists = (FilePath + "\\"+ temp).exists();
         if(!exists) {exportFile = new File(FilePath + "\\"+ temp); break;}

          }
```

where dis is a DataInputStream object. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this,

```
    File f = new File("C:\\Users\\jayesh.patel\\Desktop\\mdn.txt");
    if(f.exists()){
        boolean renameResult = f.renameTo(new File("C:\\Users\\jayesh.patel\\Desktop\\mdn1.txt"));
        if(renameResult){
            System.out.println("Rename Success");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Rename Failed");
        }
    }else{
        System.out.println("File Not Exist");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't try to second-guess the APIs. Just try to rename the file: if it fails either it is still open (Windows) or the target exists. Make a decision based on the *outcome* of `rename()` rather than trying to predict what it will do. Otherwise you are just engaged in predicting the future, so hire a big house on Knob Hill, wire it for sound, and buy yourself an Ouija board.